# xonsh: Is there a way to call a function as a command that takes optional arguments?

Tags: xonsh

I have a function in Xonsh that I'm trying to use like a command (ie: without parens). The function should optionally take arguments, however whenever I call the function without arguments, I just get the function address. How do you call a function with optional parameters?

Here's the example:

```
def _up(args, stdin=None):
    # go up any number of directories
    if not args or len(args) < 1:
        args[0] = 1
    balloons = ('../' * int(args[0]))
    # echo @(balloons)
    cd @(balloons)
aliases['up'] = _up
```

When I call `up` with no parameters, I get `<function __main__.up>`. When I call it like this, it works: `up 2`.

I could do a function like this that works, but then I can't call it without using parentheses (ie: as a command) which is what I'd prefer:

```
def up(dirs=1):
    # go up any number of directories
    balloons = ('../' * dirs)
    # echo @(balloons)
    cd @(balloons)
```

Calling `up()` and `up(2)` both work this way, but is more cumbersome than just calling `up` or `up 2`. What's the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in Xonsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why you're getting the function `repr` when you aren't passing in an argument, but a tweaked version of your function works:

```
def _up(args):  # don't need stdin
    # go up any number of directories
    if not args or len(args) < 1:
        args = [1]  # if args is None you can't index to it
    balloons = ('../' * int(args[0]))
    # echo @(balloons)
    cd @(balloons)
aliases['up'] = _up
```

on current-ish `main` of `xonsh` @ `c2f862df` this works to go up one level with just an `up` or you can specify many levels with `up 3`, etc.

Comment: Ahh... combo of a bug in my script, and the fact that I had both a function and an alias called "up" due to fighting with this. When called with no parameters, it used the function repr, when called with arguments, it used the alias. So the problem seems more with my expectation that assigning an alias would override anything else in scope. Thanks for the assist!